# jQuery slideDown with easing - jumps even with fixed height and width, no padding?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

For some reason, I am having an issue with a slideDown that seems to 'jump' at the end of the animation even on an element that has fixed height and no padding or margins.

I imagine it may be due to the easing, but what other easing function can slide a box down quickly at first and slow it down at the end smoothly?

```
$('#hello').delay(200).slideDown({
     duration: 1000,
     easing: 'easeOutExpo'
});
```

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/iqepiw

Comment: If you remove the `easing: 'easeOutExpo'` it looks nice to me

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `easing: 'easeOutExpo'` than it works like you want.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#hello').delay(200).slideDown({
  duration: 1000
 });
});
```

Comment: Yes but this doesn't achieve the easing effect I want: fast at first, slow in the end.

Comment: I found another way to do this effect you can use `$('#hello').delay(200).animate({
    height: "70"
  }, 1500, "easeOutExpo", function(){});` you only have to take out the `display: none;` and change the `height: 70px;` to `height: 0` if this helps please accept my answer.